# Blackbody radiation source

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, instrument

I have an instrument in the lab which needs to be calibrated. Ideally, it needs to be calibrated using a device that produces near-perfect blackbodies called a "blackbody calibration source". An example of such a device is shown in the following link: https://www.advancedenergy.com/products/temperature-measurement/calibration-sources/low-temperature-calibration-sources/mikron-m340/

The issue which I face is that such devices cost several thousand dollars, and our lab is not able to afford this. Because we need to calibrate the instrument with a source of known temperature and emissivity, I wonder if there is any cheap and easy way to produce blackbody spectra with known temperature and emissivity instead of using a "blackbody calibration source".

I would appreciate any recommendations on how to create reliable blackbody spectra without buying an expensive device.